# BufferedOutputStream Android (Writing to external storage)

Tags: android, android-external-storage, bufferedoutputstream

I have a problem writing to the external storage in android simulator.
If you track down the `BufferedOutputStream` in the attached screenshot. For some reason when I write to the internal storage, to cache, or external storage using `getExternalFilesDir()`, that very same code works perfectly.

But when I try to write on the Public external storage using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` that Buffer is always null. And when I to manually create the txt file where I'm saving the data, I receive the error in the screenshot below.

As per the screenshots, I've include Manifest code, the Activity class code, and screenshot from the emulator.

Any comments would be helpful.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Android studio 1.5 . Android 6 Marshmallow. Mini  SDK 19.